# Columns overlap when using "Ben Howdle Easy Peasy Equal Heights Faux Columns"

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using Ben Howdle's javascript solution to faux columns. He has two implementations that he addresses on his site: http://benhowdle.im/easy-peasy-equal-heights.html

One is for one row and the other is for two rows.

I'm using it on two rows. I used the snippet of code he suggested using in place of the code he gave for one row.

I'm wondering if he left that information out or if I did something wrong since. It works fine if I load the page at a certain size but once I start resizing, columns overlap. Here's my url example: http://lucillekenney-demos.com/prototype1.html

This is the code he suggests for multiple sets on a page:

```
<div class="sameHeights">
    <div data-key="sameHeights"></div>
    <div data-key="sameHeights"></div>
    <div data-key="sameHeights"></div>
    <div data-key="sameHeights"></div>
    <div data-key="sameHeights"></div>
</div>

<div class="otherSameHeights">
    <div data-key="otherSameHeights"></div>
    <div data-key="otherSameHeights"></div>
    <div data-key="otherSameHeights"></div>
    <div data-key="otherSameHeights"></div>
    <div data-key="otherSameHeights"></div>
</div>

and 

<script type="text/javascript">
    if ('addEventListener' in window) {
        // first group
        window.addEventListener('resize', function(){
            sameHeights('[data-key="sameHeights"]');
        });
        window.addEventListener('load', function(){
            sameHeights('[data-key="sameHeights"]');
        });

        // second group
        window.addEventListener('resize', function(){
            sameHeights('[data-key="otherSameHeights"]');
        });
        window.addEventListener('load', function(){
            sameHeights('[data-key="otherSameHeights"]');
        });
    }
</script>
```

But he doesn't give any suggestions for changes to the actual function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function sameHeights(selector) {
        var selector = selector || '[data-key="sameHeights"]',
            query = document.querySelectorAll(selector),
            elements = query.length,
            max = 0;
        if (elements) {
            while (elements--) {
                var element = query[elements];
                if (element.clientHeight > max) {
                    max = element.clientHeight;
                }
            }
            elements = query.length;
            while (elements--) {
                var element = query[elements];
                element.style.height = max + 'px';
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Second part to this question is when the window resizes to mobile view, the single columns have a lot of space between them.  The javascript equal heights is not needed for single column and needs to be deactivated at this one.

Comment: Looks like a case for flexbox to me.

Comment: I emailed Ben and got a response. He hadn't seen this issue before but he had a solution for it. “clientHeight” to “scrollHeight” inside your `eqheights.js` file. It worked.

Comment: Thank you @Paulie_D ... I plan on looking at flexbox at some point.